# Convert POJO to Map<String, String>?

Tags: java

I am looking for a utility to convert an entire pojo to `Map<String,String>`.
I can see examples all over, where pojo is converted to `Map<String,Object>`.

But i am specifically looking for `Map<String,String>`.

Comment: Step 1: Use those _examples_ to create a `Map<String, Object>`. Step 2: Iterate on it and call `toString()` on the values, collect into a `Map<String, String>`, done.

Comment: It is normal to have pojo to map as Map<String,Object> I would suggest to use it as it is.
In you prefer Map<String,String> you need extra step converting the initial map to your expected result.

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132827/how-to-convert-java-class-to-mapstring-string-and-convert-non-string-members ?

Comment: Thanks this helps.. ill try this out..

Comment: Are you trying to convert your pojo to something like a JSON format?

Comment: yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is important to understand what will be the key and value in terms of POJO. You can override POJO's toString and use it as a value.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("key1", new POJO("Done").toString());
        result.put("key2", new POJO("Clarke").toString());

    }
}


public class POJO {
    private String name;

    public POJO(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

If the field name is used as the key, you can use reflection. Be careful, if you change the field modifier in POJO to private, you will need to change the code a little. Read about reflection.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {

    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

    POJO pojo = new POJO("okGoogle", 12345);
    Class classPOJO = pojo.getClass();

    Field [] allFields = classPOJO.getFields();
    for(Field field : allFields){
        String key = field.getName();
        String value = null;
        if( field.get(pojo) != null){
            value = field.get(pojo).toString();
        }
            result.put(key, value);
        }

        System.out.println(result.get("name"));
        System.out.println(result.get("id"));

    }
}
```

and **POJO** model

```
public class POJO {
    public String name;
    public int id;

    public POJO(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi,  i want a utility for this and i dont want to specifically access each field in the Pojo ...

Comment: @Jcoder I don't quite understand. The map must contain the key as the name of the POJO field? And the value?

Comment: yes, the name of the field should be the key, and the value should be the value. If value is null , then null.

Comment: @Jcoder, I'll add the solution to my answer above, expect it.

Comment: @ JDocer Read the answer again, have I solved your problem?

Comment: Thanks it helps ! Although i felt Traycho's comment has a leaner solution.. what do you think ?

Comment: @Jcoder Yes, it probably takes a little less code, but if we use reflection, we can fine-tune it. It's up to you, all the best)

Answer (score 0):

i am converting each pojo to map and than creating a map to store all maps representing
pojo class.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person person = new Person();
           person.setName("Abhishek");
           person.setAge("30");

    Person person1 = new Person();
           person1.setName("Abhi");
           person1.setAge("28");

    Map<String,  Map<String, String>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("name", person.getName());
    result.put("age", person.getAge());
    resultMap.put("object1", result);

    result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("name", person1.getName());
    result.put("age", person1.getAge());
        resultMap.put("object2", result);
    }
}

public class Person {
    private String name;

    private String age

   //setters and getters

}
```